# Expected an indented block, can't find out where or why

Tags: python

I can't seem to figure out why my program won't run. It keeps saying expected an indented block I tried going back making sure I didn't indent too many times or too little but I can't seem to find the problem. Can anyone help? Please and thank you.

```
import random

userChoice = eval(input("Scissor (0), Rock (1), Paper (2)"))

computerChoice = random.randint(0,2)
if computerChoice == 0:
elif computerChoice == 1:
elif computerChoice == 2:

if userChoice == 0:
elif userChoice == 1:
elif userChoice == 2:

if userChoice == 0 and computerChoice == 0:
    print("The computer is Scissors. You are Scissors. It's a tie!")
elif userChoice == 0 and computerChoice == 1:
    print("The computer is Rock. You are Scissors. You lost")
elif userChoice == 0 and computerChoice == 2:
    print("The computer is Paper. You are Scissors. You won!")

if userChoice == 1 and computerChoice == 0:
    print("The computer is Scissors. You are Rock. You won!")
elif userChoice == 1 and computerChoice == 1:
    print("The computer is Rock. You are Rock. It's a tie!")
elif userChoice == 1 and computerChoice == 2:
    print("The computer is Paper. You are Rock. You lost")

if userChoice == 2 and computerChoice == 0:
    print("The computer is Scissors. You are Paper. You lost")
elif userChoice == 2 and computerChoice == 1:
    print("The computer is Rock. You are Paper. You won!")
elif userChoice == 2 and computerChoice == 2:
    print("The computer is Paper. You are Paper. It's a tie!")
```

Comment: You have empty if/elif statements. Also, use `int()` instead of `eval()`.

Comment: @AndrewL. Hi Andrew, what do you mean by I have empty if/elif statements? I don't understand.

Comment: you cannot have a control statement that is empty, so having `if ... :` without any statements inside it is invalid

Comment: Look at lines 6-8, lines 10-12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There needs to be a body to those empty if/elif statements

Example (python 2 style):

```
if computerChoice == 0:
    print 'Something needs to be done here'
elif computerChoice == 1:
    print 'Something needs to be done here too'
elif computerChoice == 2:
    print 'And something needs to be done here, too'
```

Obviously replace those print statements with some implementation of what you are trying to do. But there  cannot be nothing there.

Exception - a **pass** statement is acceptable if you really want to do nothing.

```
if computerChoice == 0:
    pass # do nothing here
elif computerChoice == 1:
    pass # do nothing here
elif computerChoice == 2:
    pass # do nothing here
```

Comment: I was not aware that the if/elif needs body to the statements as I thought the if/elif were already statements. Sorry I am pretty new to coding. Thank you for clarifying, much appreciated.

Comment: @DandyPotato: But why would you have those `if` and `elif` statements if you don't want to do anything when the condition is met?

Comment: You could want to do something if only one of the conditions out of 3 was satisfied, for instance, and do nothing for the other 2 conditions. Using pass for all of the conditions would not make sense, but it might for only some conditions.

Comment: @Mathias although in this case that may not apply

Answer (score 0):

The statement after colon `:` is missing in the if-elif block. You can try adding `pass`.

> The pass statement in Python is used when a statement is required
>   syntactically but you do not want any command or code to execute.

```
computerChoice = random.randint(0,2)
if computerChoice == 0:
    pass
elif computerChoice == 1:
    pass
elif computerChoice == 2:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you for informing me about the command pass, I just tried it and it works :). I am pretty new to coding still.